# personal file version controller with a twist

Tags: version-control

I am on a windows machine. I would like to setup a personal version control system in my machine. Plus I would like to maybe have a copy of the same system in a remote server for backup.

can anyone please advise me how do I go about it plus are there any free backup servers available which I can use to backup by version control files remotely?

Shanthi

Answer (score 1):

Install git and use github for backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **any DCVS** for such task, final choice is extremely subjective (Mercurial, Bazaar, Monotone, Fossil). From my POV:

- Mercurial is better and more elegant way to go, than Git. Also
  "first-class citizen" for Win-world, compare to Git
- Bazaar was
  implemented just terribly Fossil is nice for personal and small-team
  usage, but **not fit** nicely to *any workflow*
- Monotone is extremely
  slow in network communication